# Why does 'ping' not output a summary when redirecting output?

Tags: linux, signals, ping, tee

I can ping *google.com* for several seconds and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, a brief summary is displayed at the bottom:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.131.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lu-in-f113.1e100.net (74.125.131.113): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=46.7 ms
64 bytes from lu-in-f113.1e100.net (74.125.131.113): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=45.0 ms
64 bytes from lu-in-f113.1e100.net (74.125.131.113): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=54.5 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 3 received, 25% packet loss, time 3009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 44.965/48.719/54.524/4.163 ms
```

However, when I do the same redirecting output to log file with `tee`, the summary is not displayed:

```
$ ping google.com | tee log
PING google.com (74.125.131.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lu-in-f113.1e100.net (74.125.131.113): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=34.1 ms
64 bytes from lu-in-f113.1e100.net (74.125.131.113): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=57.0 ms
64 bytes from lu-in-f113.1e100.net (74.125.131.113): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=50.9 ms
^C
```

Can I get the summary as well when redirecting output with `tee`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Turns out that there is an option in `tee` to ignore interrupt signals which are sent when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed. From [man tee](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html):

```
   -i, --ignore-interrupts
          ignore interrupt signals
```

When whole pipeline is interrupted by `SIGINT`, this signal is sent to all processes in pipeline. The problem is that `tee` is usually receiving `SIGINT` earlier than `ping` and then killing `ping` with `SIGPIPE`. If `SIGINT` is ignored in `tee`, it will be delivered only to `ping` and the summary will be displayed:

```
$ ping google.com | tee --ignore-interrupts log 
PING google.com (142.250.150.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from la-in-f101.1e100.net (142.250.150.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=104 time=48.8 ms
64 bytes from la-in-f101.1e100.net (142.250.150.101): icmp_seq=2 ttl=104 time=51.0 ms
64 bytes from la-in-f101.1e100.net (142.250.150.101): icmp_seq=3 ttl=107 time=32.2 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 32.198/44.005/50.973/8.394 ms
```

So `ping` receiving `SIGINT` will terminate eventually, causing `tee` to see the pipe writer had died, eventually causing `tee` to terminate, too (after having "digested" the input so far).

Answer (score 61):

`ping` shows the summary when it is killed with `SIGINT`, *e.g.* as a result of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, or when it has transmitted the requested number of packets (the `-c` option). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> causes `SIGINT` to be sent to all processes in the foreground process group, *i.e.* in this scenario all the processes in the pipeline (`ping` and `tee`). `tee` doesn’t catch `SIGINT` (on Linux, look at `SigCgt` in `/proc/$(pgrep tee)/status`), so when it receives the signal, it dies, closing its end of the pipe. What happens next is a race: if `ping` was still outputting, it will die with `SIGPIPE` before it gets the `SIGINT`; if it gets the `SIGINT` before outputting anything, it will try to output its summary and die with `SIGPIPE`. In any case, there’s no longer anywhere for the output to go.

To get the summary, arrange to kill only `ping` with `SIGINT`:

```
killall -INT ping
```

or run it with a pre-determined number of packets:

```
ping -c 20 google.com | tee log
```

or (keeping the best for last), [have `tee` ignore `SIGINT`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687672/86440), as you discovered.